# Physical-button-hold shortcut on mobile

Tags: mobile, shortcut

Is it possible to utilize button-hold on mobile phone as a trigger for some programmed action? E.g. my app runs in background and it is programmed to open up if I hold both volume up and volume down buttons for 3 seconds.

I want to make iPhone/Android app. I haven't choose any framework yet, it's a question of technical possibility of such an idea, but I'll probably use objective-C/Swift as I have an iPhone.

Comment: What tools are you working with? If you're making an android/iphone app, yes. If you're making a web app, theoretically no. Can you specify the use case a bit more? It's really hard to go on what you've given us.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of web app, but you're right, that the question wasn't clear enough. I've just edited it. Could you answer how do one do that for a android/iphone app? I'm not using any tools yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an information for iOS on how to use events from volume buttons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons), however it seems to be [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013827/listen-for-ios-device-power-button-presses) to use events from power button or home button in the background, except from noticing that the app went from foreground to the background at home/power-button action.